# approach integrate solr and mysql

Tags: mysql, import, solr, integration

I'm building a web application with php and mysql. Web application will have 3-4 big tables (milions of records per table) where it will extremely important that it must be possible perform a full text search on it for search a term in text field. I design this web application with mysql because it need full acid support and transaction. Now I'm trying understand how perform query for search result in this 3-4 big data tables by terms (multiple word) in a faster way.

I'm considering Solr For store old data,I think that I can build a periodically cron job that import data from mysql into solr but but I don't understand:

- how can I query fresh result with mysql if user search a text that has just insert a few seconds ago, from instead user search a old text insert for example 2 days ago?

and if user modify a old data:

- How can I update instantly record match on salr for to be instantly modified data visible from others user.

also

- if a user update a old data correctly on mysql (in a transaction) and immediately next application try update also data in solr for refresh with new data value but doesn't work well, user already could see old data, not new data, because solr has already old data because update fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr has an [XML interface](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#add.2BAC8-replace_documents) for submitting documents to be indexed. Every time the searchable data in your application is updated, you can submit a add/update request to solr, which will then "instantly" index that data.

Comment: ok, but if my application make different update inside a transaction and commit it and then send request to solr for update index but solr update request fail, I obtain that on mysql it is all ok, instead in solr index isnt' updated. User then search and he find that record doesn't have update because solr fail request. So I need all update perform by mysql and request perform in solr into in a single transaction, So i fail something, I get untouch data as in mysql as in solr. Is it possible?

Comment: If I understand you correctly so you need 100% consistency between MySQL and your Solr instance. Solr has a java client, [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj); you could do your mysql commit and the Solr update inside a single transaction, rolling back the commit to MySQL if the solr update fails.

Comment: ok, thanks. Is it possible also use php driver for solr for obtain even so 100% consistency between mysql and solr? If I have big data, an update index on solr take more times? because you say "instantly",so it seems that take time to build index for document change and user that make an update in that moment can't wait for long time request.

Comment: No clue about php support for solr. If you mean that the data that you're indexing in solr for each update is large, then obviously there's going to be network overhead, and if it's really really large, there'll be some overhead for Solr as well (though solr is very fast). After you've done the data transfer, Solr only has to build the index for the single updated document, not the entire DB, so that aspect of the update shouldn't take too long. The best way to see if this works for your data is to test it.